# Error : Argument 1 passed to DOMNode::appendChild() must be an instance of DOMNode, string given

Tags: php, dom, yii2

My code looks like this

```
     $xml = new \DOMDocument();
      .
      .
      .   
     $VAST_Impression ="some_url"
     $xml_Impression = $xml->Impression= htmlspecialchars($VAST_Impression);
     $xml_InLine->appendChild($xml_Impression);
```

I get error like this:

> PHP Recoverable Error – yii\base\ErrorException
>
> Argument 1 passed to DOMNode::appendChild() must be an instance of DOMNode, string given

Comment: what does it mean? im newbie pls help

Comment: It means that the first argument to appendChild needs to be an instance of DOMNode, but you've passed in a string. I.e. `$xml_Impression` is a string, but it needs to be an instance of DOMNode.

Comment: does that mean i should use createElement() instead of htmlspecialchars()? because if I use createElement i cant use '&' in the url which is why I changed to htmlspecialchars()....anyway out?

Comment: `createElement` will give you a `DOMElement` which is an extension of `DOMNode`, so yes. You can still encode the content of what you pass into the node.

Comment: @JonStirling i get this error after changing to createElement DOMDocument::createElement(): unterminated entity reference

Comment: You still need the encoding, just put the return of that into `createElement`. I.e. `createElement(htmlspecialchars($string))`

Comment: @JonStirling awesome. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coudl you accessing in wrong way to the method

```
$xml_Impression = $xml->Impression->htmlspecialchars($VAST_Impression);
```

or  you are using the wrong method

```
$xml_Impression = $xml->Impression->createElement($VAST_Impression);
```

eg :

```
$xml_Impression = $xml->Impression->createElement('your_tag', $VAST_Impression);
```

Comment: yes this solves the problem but I can't pass parameters in the url `$VAST_Impression` it gives me this error `DOMDocument::createElement(): unterminated entity reference `

Comment: You must pass c a valid content .. check for the real string content and be sure is valid for createElement ..answer  udpated .. you need  a tag and a value